# Update sqlite3 database from python server file

Tags: python, database, sqlite, jwt

I have this code for server file:

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from urllib.parse import parse_qs
import sqlite3
import jwt
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

conn = sqlite3.connect('catalog.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users(
id INT PRIMARY KEY,
name_lastname TEXT,
account INT,
password TEXT,
token TEXT)
""")

conn.commit()

users = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Users")

if (len(users.fetchall()) == 0):
    user = [('1', 'user1', '123', '123', ''),
            ('2', 'user2', '124', '124', ''),
            ('3', 'user3', '125', '125', '')]
    cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO Users VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", user)
    conn.commit()

class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.log_message("Incoming GET request...")
        try:
            account = parse_qs(self.path[2:])['account'][0]

        except:
            self.send_response_to_client(404, 'Incorrect parameters provided')
            self.log_message("Incorrect parameters provided")
            return

    def do_POST(self):
        self.log_message('Incoming POST request...')
        data_passed = parse_qs(self.path[2:])

        try:
            data = cursor.execute("SELECT %s FROM Users WHERE %s=? and %s=?" %
                                  ("account", "account", "password"),
                                  (data_passed['account'][0],
                                   data_passed['password'][0]), )
            if (len(data.fetchall()) == 0):
                self.send_response_to_client(400, 'Invalid login')
            else:
                encoded = jwt.encode({'account': data_passed['account'][0],
                                      'exp': datetime.utcnow() +
                                             timedelta(seconds=45)}, 'secret',
                                     algorithm='HS256')

                # I gues that code for database update goes here

                self.send_response_to_client(200, 'Token (valid for 45 sec): {}'.format(encoded))

        except KeyError:
            self.send_response_to_client(404, 'Incorrect parameters provided')
            self.log_message("Incorrect parameters provided")

    def send_response_to_client(self, status_code, data):
        self.send_response(status_code)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/plain')
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(str(data).encode())


server_address = ('127.0.0.1', 8079)
http_server = HTTPServer(server_address, RequestHandler)
http_server.serve_forever()
```

and this is the code for client file:

```
import requests
import jwt

account = input("Enter your account: ")
password = input("Enter your password: ")

r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8079/", params={'account': account, 'password': password})
print("Request method: POST,  \nResponse status_code: {}, \n" \
          "Response data: {}".format(r.status_code, r.text))
```

All this working fine eg. when user is loged in jwt token is generated and printed in console (terminal). Now I need to write that token in database in field "token" for loged in user (based on account number), something like this (UPDATE Users SET token=encoded WHERE account=account). I tryed every solution that I find here or googling it but with no success. Can somebody help for correct syntax and where to put it?

Second part is to print in console "Welcome + name_lastname" field from database for loged in user?

Comment: `cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET token = ? WHERE account = ?", (encoded, account))`?

Comment: Please check code's...I already try that and errror is this: NameError: name 'account' is not defined...probably because account is defined is clients file.

Comment: Then use the correct variable. `data_passed['account'][0]`

Comment: No errors with that code but token is not saved in database

Comment: Did you remember to use `conn.commit()`?

Comment: You're not the first or last, don't beat yourself up.

Comment: How can I print Welcome+name_lastname field from database for loged in user?

Comment: Change the query to select `name_lastname` instead of `account`. Assign the result of `cursor.fetchall()` to a variable, then you can get the name from `variable[0][0]`.

Comment: I'm trying but not sure how to write that query

Comment: How can you know how to write the original query, but not that query? Just change `("account", "account", "password")` to `("name_lastname", "account", "password")`.

Comment: Why are you using string formatting for the column names in the query? Just write the query normally. `SELECT name_lastname FROM users WHERE account = ? and password = ?`

Comment: ok, I got that working but now it is printed on server, I need to put that code in clients file.Do I must to stablish connection to database from clients file also?

Comment: I don't know anything about that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use an `UPDATE` query to add `encoded` as the `token` to the user's row.
2. Change the `SELECT` query to get the name from the table, and display that in the console.

```
def do_POST(self):
        self.log_message('Incoming POST request...')
        data_passed = parse_qs(self.path[2:])

        try:
            data = cursor.execute("SELECT name_lastname FROM Users WHERE account=? and password=?",
                                  (data_passed['account'][0],
                                   data_passed['password'][0]), )
            row = data.fetchone()
            if not row:
                self.send_response_to_client(400, 'Invalid login')
            else:
                encoded = jwt.encode({'account': data_passed['account'][0],
                                      'exp': datetime.utcnow() +
                                             timedelta(seconds=45)}, 'secret',
                                     algorithm='HS256')

                cursor.execute("UPDATE Users SET token = ? WHERE account = ?", (data_passed['account'][0],))
                self.send_response_to_client(200, 'Welcome {}. Token (valid for 45 sec): {}'.format(row[0], encoded))

        except KeyError:
            self.send_response_to_client(404, 'Incorrect parameters provided')
            self.log_message("Incorrect parameters provided")
```

Comment: this is also working, butwelcome is printed on server file and I need it to be printed in clients file

Comment: I originally put it in the `send_response_to_client()` string. But then I read the question and you said you wanted it to be printed on the console, so I used `print()` instead.

Comment: it's ok to be in send_response...it is working now, thanks again.

Comment: I just misunderstood what you were saying in the question.